# How does WCF actually work?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created a C# application that I want to split into server and client side. The client side should have only a UI, and the server side should manage logic and database.

But, I'm not sure about something: my application should be used by many users at the same time. If I move my application to a server, will WCF create another instance of the application for every user that logs in or there's only one instance of the application for all users?

If the second scenario is true, then how do I create separate application instances for every user that want to use my service? I want to keep my application logic on the server, to make users share the same database, but also to make every single instance independent (so several users can use the WCF service with different data). Someting like PHP does: same code, new instance of code for every user, shared database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, WCF is stateless and instanceless. This basically means that any call may be issued by any client, without any clients or calls knowing about each other.

As long as you have kept that in mind while designing the service, you're good to go. What problems do you expect to occur, given how your service is built at this moment?

Comment: Well, i have created my app without any plan to split it, so my app is exchanging objects. Practically it's an game (just without graphics). So i need that all users have shared database but different data they seen on their client UI. With that in mind, i think that server will have to have some idea about everything every user has in his lists for example (what is 3rd element in lstItems of 4th users?).

Comment: No, you'd have to create a `void AddItemToList(int userId, Item item)` call to store items that users pick up, and a `List<Item> GetItems(int userId)` call to get the list of objects from another user.

Comment: But, if i create a List<Item> object on WCF side (and store Item passed to "AddItemToList" method), will that list get filled by data from all users that use service in that particular moment?

Comment: No, that's what the userId parameter is for. You need to know for who a given request is, and one of many ways is add a parameter identifying a user to all service methods. You then use that ID to store/retrieve items per user in a database. You have to, since the WCF process doesn't "live", and it doesn't know about other users that are connected. They actually communicate through the data in the database.

Comment: Persistence and state on the server-side should be handled by means of something actually persistent - like a database or file.  You can cache things in memory, but you shouldn't really rely on it.  Rely on something solid, like a database.  This applies to WCF as web services, by the way.  If you're doing something like a game you might want to consider a different technology, but it will be more technically difficult to implement by quite a margin.

Comment: Yes, i already heard that WCF might be a problem for a game because poor performance :\ but i just don't know what else to use. I have considered to use even a Linq for database management (to simplify things) but it turns out that Linq is also "no-no" for a multi user game :\ I'm working on this alone (over a period of time, few years when i got some spare time) and that's why i wanted to keep thing as simple as possible.

Comment: Writing a multiplayer game is not an easy project, and unless you have extensive experience or have spent a great deal of time researching, start very, very, very simple, or you are likely doomed to fail.  For example: start with a chat program, then maybe a multiplayer 'number guessing game'.  You will have to take baby steps, I guarantee it.

Answer (score 2):

The server-side (handled by WCF) will usually not hold any state at all: all method calls would be self-contained and fairly atomic.  For example, `GetUsers`, `AddOrder` etc.  So there's no 'instance' of the app, and in fact the WCF service does not know that it's a particular app using it.

This is on purpose: if you wanted to write a web app, or simple query tool, it could use those same methods on the WCF service without having to be an 'app', or create an instance of anything on the server.

WCF can have objects with a long lifetime, that are stateful, a bit like remoting, but if you're following the pattern of 99.9% of other designs with WCF, you'll be using WCF as a web service.

*Edit*: from the sounds of your comments, you need to do some seriously and potentially in-depth reading about client-server architectures and the use of WCF.  Start from scratch with something small, then try to apply it to your current application.

Comment: So, i can't use some "List<objects>" object to store temp data needed only while particular user is loged in?

Comment: There is a way you could, but it's not the way you should be thinking.  An application, except in extremely rare and exceptional circumstances, is a client-side thing.  If you need to cache data like that, it probably relates to a particular user, which of course is something that happens on the client.

Comment: But if i keep my logic on the client side and use wcf just for storing data (just like i intended in the beginning) than any user could mess up with my code and practically hack a game (gain some advantage) :)

Comment: Any important data would be stored on the server, which the client does not have access to.. that's the whole point isn't it?  There would be some server-side logic, and you would not have a method `SetScore` for example, you'd have `KilledPlayer` instead - so you would say `KilledPlayer()` rather than `SetScore(1000)` so the server calcs the new score.